# Running Report Issue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

While we are running a report for a user in SSRS we are facing the following issue:
"An error occurred during client rendering.
An error occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'Main 2'."

Could you guys help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: Its telling you that there was an error when running the dataset query for "Main 2". run the same query with the exact same parameters in SSMS or similar and you should see the error.

Comment: Please share your error with us